# Accumulate[] on an ordered HashTable

Tags: associations, functional-style

Hopefully this is a trivial question, but I keep getting lost looking for an answer in the documentation.

I have an ordered HashTable containing indexed real numbers:

`oht = <|a -> 1.224, b -> 1.096, c -> 1.886|>`

I want to get running totals for this data, which I can do using Accumulate:

`Accumulate[Values[oht]]`

However, this gets me an array:

`{1.224,2.32,4.206}`

Is there a simple way to get the array in an ordered HashTable? That is, I want to preserve the indexes, like this:

`<|a -> 1.224, b -> 2.32, c -> 4.206|>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Module[{acc = 0}, Map[acc += # &, oht]]

(* <|a -> 1.224, b -> 2.32, c -> 4.206|> *)
```

but this will not be the winner in the speed competition, and uses mutable state. Other methods will likely involve deconstructing an original assoc and creating a new one, like e.g. the following:

```
AssociationThread[Keys @ oht, Accumulate @ Values @ oht]

(* <|a -> 1.224, b -> 2.32, c -> 4.206|> *)
```